# A json response into a utilized-dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I'm trying to parse the following response (JSON Response), here's a sample:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/fywkWrox-IkW0v2IWY27RMiWvvA\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CBQQAA",
  "regionCode": "IQ",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 20
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/j0uEstXCXOhrDqDegEBmEeHqsBM\"",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "YQHsXMglC9A"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2015-10-23T06:54:18.000Z",
        "channelId": "UComP_epzeKzvBX156r6pm1Q",
        "title": "Adele - Hello",
        "description": "'Hello' is taken from the new album, 25, out November 20. http://adele.com Available now from iTunes http://smarturl.it/itunes25 Available now from Amazon ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YQHsXMglC9A/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YQHsXMglC9A/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YQHsXMglC9A/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AdeleVEVO",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
      }
    }
```

And this is my parsing function:

```
  def parse(self):
        items = self['items']
        i = 0
        for item in items:
            Data = {str(i): {
                "id": item['id']['videoId'],
                "title": item['snippet']['title'],
                "description": item['snippet']['description'],
                "thumbnail": item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                "publishedAt": item['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                "FullURL": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item['id']['videoId']
            }}
            i = i +1
        return Data
```

The main problem is that the dictionary is only inserting the last bit of the response, for example, I'm fetching 10 results, and it's only returning the last response. What's the problem?

Comment: Because `Data` doesn't exist before your `for` loop, so is constantly being redefined. You end up `returning` its final incarnation.

Comment: Useful read : http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the definition of `Data` out of the `for` loop, initialise it as an empty dictionary and then add key/value pairs to it on each iteration. Currently, you keep redefining the entire dictionary on each loop, containing a single entry. You then end up `return`ing the final version.

```
def parse(self):
        items = self['items']
        Data = {} # Initialise it here
        for i, item in enumerate(items): # Now you don't need to increment i
            # Insert your key/value pair
            Data[str(i)] = {
                "id": item['id']['videoId'],
                "title": item['snippet']['title'],
                "description": item['snippet']['description'],
                "thumbnail": item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                "publishedAt": item['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                "FullURL": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item['id']['videoId']
            }

        return Data
```